# Need to create a copy of an record in the same Access table and then update the data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the access 2016 inventory database which will not get larger that 20000 records.
I updated the inventory table with the multi selection fields that I require to manage my inventory and everything is working fine in term of adding new records and updated existing records using the add and update macros in the tables forms.

Now I want to be able to create a copy of an existing record, make an update and then save it in to the same inventory table so I have an historical data of updated parts and then update the form to only show the latest record

I very new to access and coding so I'm sure I'm breaking some sort of modelling rule and have tried the following to get this to work with no success:

***Creating updated record in same table
*create a append query but access does not support muilti selection fields
*create a macro to copy and paste the existing record to update and paste the new version of the record into the inventory table (Seems Copy and Paste are not support in Macro)
*create a VBA that create a copy of the existing record, I can get this to create a copy but this only works after I have made the update to the record, which means I am left with two copies of the update record and not the original and updated record

*** filter the Form to only show the latest record
*No idea where to start!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.  It may not be the most elegant a solution but it is the best I can think of without more context.

You would need a distinct Primary Key ID field that is not an autonumber on your inventory table.
You copy the data from the current record into a new record that has an ID field above 20000 using whatever method you choose (e.g., button on the form).

```
recid = DMax("ID", "tblInventory") + 1
If recid < 20001 then
    recid=20001
End if
mySQL = "INSERT INTO tblInventory (recid, field2, etc.) VALUES (" & recid & ", '" & _
        txtField1.Value & "','" & txtField2.Value & "," & etc.
CurrentDB.Execute mySQL
```

and then edit the existing record with the new data.

When your form loads have the query it is based on only find records below 20000

You have your legacy data which you can query separately, and your new data which will be the only thing seen in your form.